# Android Collapsing Toolbar: the header image overlap the content at the first

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using Collapsing Toolbar to build an parallax header image for my details activity.

It works well except for the first time when i open the activity. At that time, the header image is expanded by default BUT it overlaps a part the content (the nested scroll view).

What i want is the nested scroll view start from the end of header image, not from the top of screen then it won't be overlapped by parallax image.

I don't have any ideal now. Did you face it before? Please give me a hand!

Below is the xml code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_100"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:transitionName="cover"
                android:src="@drawable/room"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/tb_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Did you figure out the issue???

Comment: @hushed_voice sorry but i don't remember. It's too long time ago :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, it solved my problem

```
<ImageView ...
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

and if you are using recycler view inside NestedScrollView then set`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView ...
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```

Comment: Worked for me for recycleview